# For package enuimitem, have unique differing \itemsep for some items

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem, kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[Item 1] \kant[1]
        \item[Item 2] \kant[2-3]
        \item[Item 3] \kant[4]
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

producing the output [image: 4 paragraphs of kantlipsum in an enumitem enumeration] minus the red marks.

For the one single `\itemsep` marked in red, I want the list to use a different (smaller) value than the default items. I know how to define a custom item, but how do I make it use a different `\itemsep` than the rest of the `enumerate` environment?

Comment: Why do you want a smaller value?

Comment: @ulrike-fischer: Me wanting a smaller value might seem weird in this MWE, however in my document I have different kinds of items, some which always follow another and are associated to them. Thus, a smaller `\itemsep` should indicate them being somehow related.

@zarko: It is an option, however I hoped to have an option within the scope of `enumitem`. If anyone can provide me with this, I'd prefer it; Else you should turn your comment into an answer and I would gladly accept it.

Comment: I suspected something like this and imho no reader will really realize that the items are "somehow related" from a bit smaller space.

Comment: Of course I use different labeling and indenting mechanisms for these types of items, so I find the spacing justified, but the intention behind this question should in my opinion be outside the scope of answering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a negative `\vspace` to remove the item separation (which actually includes a `\parskip`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=\baselineskip]
  \item[Item 1] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Maecenas semper mattis eros eget malesuada. Curabitur ut dolor metus. 
    Vivamus condimentum nisi eu tincidunt aliquet.

  \item[Item 2] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Maecenas semper mattis eros eget malesuada. Curabitur ut dolor metus. 
    Vivamus condimentum nisi eu tincidunt aliquet.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Maecenas semper mattis eros eget malesuada. Curabitur ut dolor metus. 
    Vivamus condimentum nisi eu tincidunt aliquet.

  \vspace{\dimexpr-\itemsep-\parskip}% Remove item separation

  \item[Item 3] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Maecenas semper mattis eros eget malesuada. Curabitur ut dolor metus. 
    Vivamus condimentum nisi eu tincidunt aliquet.

  \item[Item 4] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Maecenas semper mattis eros eget malesuada. Curabitur ut dolor metus. 
    Vivamus condimentum nisi eu tincidunt aliquet.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

You may also use

```
\vspace{\dimexpr-\itemsep-\parskip+3pt}
```

if you want the gap to be `3pt`. The `-\itemsep-\parskip` removes whatever space the lists inserts at the top of a new `\item` (not the first `\item`), so adding a length should show exactly that as being the gap between the `\item`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `two` (or more) enumerate environments and the `resume` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem, kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
        \item[Item 1] \kant[1]
        \item[Item 2] \kant[2-3]
    \end{enumerate}
        \begin{enumerate}[resume, before=\leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\topsep+\partopsep\relax}]
        \item[Item 3] \kant[4]
        \item[Item 4] \kant[5]
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Actually I think the key point here is essentially what @zarko mentioned in his comment above (using a negative `\vspace`) plus unneccessary notational bloat. Your solution would require me to carefully define different`\itemsep` for two different `enumerate` environments and break those apart whenever I want  a differently spaced item. Therefore I see it preferrable to just insert a `\vspace{-<len>}` in front of the item in question.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
A simple solution is to use `\\[-\myitemsep]` at the end of item paragraph, where you like to reduce vertical space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, kantlipsum}
\usepackage{calc}% <-- added
\newlength\myitemsep% <-- added
\setlength\myitemsep{\baselineskip+\itemsep}% <-- added

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item[Item 1] \kant[1]
        \item[Item 2] first item paragraph first item paragraph first item paragraph first item paragraph first item paragraph first item paragraph first item paragraph item paragraph item paragraph item paragraph item paragraph

            second item paragraph second item paragraph second item paragraph second item paragraph second item paragraph second item paragraph second item paragraph second item paragraph
            \\[-\myitemsep]% <-- added
        \item[Item 3] \kant[4]
        \item[Item 4] \kant[5]
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I actually think this approach is less feasible than what you suggested initially, because this way I won't be able to use it in custom items, since I won't know whether it will need to be fllowed by a small itemsep or a default one.